# How to insert 2 data from (1) textbox to 2 columns in database?

Tags: php, jquery, html

[This is my textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixyY1.png)

[This is my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGDwV.png)

```
<label> Guest Name: </label>   
<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="guest" id="guest" required>

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES ('', '$guest')");

enter code here
```

Comment: We need to see your code and what you have tried yourself to create this. While screenshots can be useful together with code, but without they rarely are any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

//suppose you enter 'Asaduzzaman Arif' in guest name field

```
$name = explode(" ", $guest);
$firstName = $name[0];
$lastName = $name[1];
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES ('', '$firstName', '$lastName')");
```

//although getting data by this type of way is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt do that, because of data validation.

You could just make a cut at the comma with something like split and use the comma as the seperator. But thats a very bad idea.
If you would do this, you should also do it in your backend in php, here is an example:

```
$array = (explode(",",$str));
```

You can also set a limit for the output in your array, so for first and last name :

```
$array = (explode(',',$str,2));
```

In your code it would look like this:

```
$array = (explode(',',$guest,2));

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES ('', '$array[0]', $array[1])");
```

However its a bad idea and i would suggest you just create another field for last name.

```
<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" required>

<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname" required>

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES ('', '$firstname', $lastname)");
```

If you want to validate your data or there is no comma you will get errors.

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than an actual answer to the OP's problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer & suggestion.